# Why am I getting a "None" result with uspto-opendata-python patent search?

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to pull a specific value (the inventor's name) from the USPTO's Patent Examination Data System and my code will not get the inventorName value from the search.  It is currently resulting in "None" when I try to print the result.  It does retrieve all of the information from the patent but I cannot seem to get the specific values within the dictionary.

```
from uspto.peds.client import UsptoPatentExaminationDataSystemClient
client = UsptoPatentExaminationDataSystemClient()

expression = 'patentNumber:(5555555)'
result = dict(client.search(expression))

print(result.get('inventorName'))
print(result)
```

---

The result is currently:

```html
None<br/>
{'numFound': 1, 'start': 0, 'docs': [{'applId': '08183369', 'assignments': [{'reelNumber': '7088', 'frameNumber': '469', 'addressNameText': 'SUGHRUE, MION, ZINN, MACPEAK & SEAS', 'addressLineOneText': 'ROBERT V. SLOAN', 'addressLineTwoText': '2100 PENNSYLVANIA, N.W.', 'addressLineThreeText': 'SUITE 800', 'addressLineFourText': 'WASHINGTON, D.C. 20037-3202', 'mailDate': '09-12-1994', 'receivedDate': '', 'recordedDate': '03-18-1994', 'pagesCount': '2', 'converyanceName': 'ASSIGNMENT OF ASSIGNORS INTEREST (SEE DOCUMENT FOR DETAILS).', 'sequenceNumber': '1', 'assignors': [{'assignorName': 'SATO, JUN', 'execDate': '02-24-1994'}, {'assignorName': 'SAIKI, MITSUYOSHI', 'execDate': '03-03-1994'}], 'assignee': [{'assigneeName': 'AISIN SEIKI KABUSHIKI KAISHA', 'streetLineOneText': '1, 2-CHOME, ASAHIMACHI', 'streetLineTwoText': 'null', 'cityName': 'KARIYA CITY, ACIHI PREF.', 'countryCode': 'JAPAN', 'postalCode': 'null'}]}], 'appFilingDate': '1994-01-19T00:00:00Z', 'appExamName': 'JOHNS, ANDREW W', 'appExamNameFacet': 'JOHNS, ANDREW W', 'publicInd': 'Y', 'appLocationDate': '2018-06-23T00:00:00Z', 'APP_IND': '5', 'inventorName': 'JUN  SATO', 'inventorNameFacet': 'JUN  SATO', 'corrAddrGeoRegionCode': 'DC', 'corrAddrNameLineTwo': '2100 PENNSYLVANIA AVENUE NW', 'appLocation': 'FILE REPOSITORY (FRANCONIA)', 'id': '08183369', 'appGrpArtNumber': '2606', 'appGrpArtNumberFacet': '2606', 'applIdStr': '08183369', 'appl_id_txt': '08183369', 'inventorsFullName': ['{JUN||SATO},{MITSUYOSHI||SAIKI}'], 'inventorsFullNameFacet': '{JUN||SATO},{MITSUYOSHI||SAIKI}', 'appSubCls': '104000', 'patentNumber': '5555555', 'LAST_MOD_TS': '2017-03-04T07:27:30Z', 'transactions': [{'recordDate': '2017-03-04 00:00:00', 'code': 'TRIALDIS', 'description': 'Request for Trial Dismissed'}, {'recordDate': '1996-09-10 00:00:00', 'code': 'PGM/', 'description': 'Recordation of Patent Grant Mailed'}, {'recordDate': '1996-08-05 00:00:00', 'code': 'WPIR', 'description': 'Issue Notification Mailed'}, {'recordDate': '1996-06-18 00:00:00', 'code': 'N084', 'description': 'Issue Fee Payment Verified'}, {'recordDate': '1996-03-20 00:00:00', 'code': 'MC/N=', 'description': 'Mail Corrected Notice of Allowance'}, {'recordDate': '1996-03-20 00:00:00', 'code': 'C/N=', 'description': 'Corrected Notice of Allowance'}, {'recordDate': '1996-03-13 00:00:00', 'code': 'MN/=.', 'description': 'Mail Notice of Allowance'}, {'recordDate': '1996-03-13 00:00:00', 'code': 'N/=.', 'description': 'Notice of Allowance Data Verification Completed'}, {'recordDate': '1996-03-13 00:00:00', 'code': 'MEX.A', 'description': "Mail Examiner's Amendment"}, {'recordDate': '1996-03-13 00:00:00', 'code': 'EX.A', 'description': "Examiner's Amendment Communication"}, {'recordDate': '1996-03-08 00:00:00', 'code': 'FWDX', 'description': 'Date Forwarded to Examiner'}, {'recordDate': '1996-02-29 00:00:00', 'code': 'A.QU', 'description': 'Response after Ex Parte Quayle Action'}, {'recordDate': '1996-02-29 00:00:00', 'code': 'LTDR', 'description': 'Incoming Letter Pertaining to the Drawings'}, {'recordDate': '1995-12-29 00:00:00', 'code': 'MCTEQ', 'description': 'Mail Ex Parte Quayle Action (PTOL - 326)'}, {'recordDate': '1995-12-19 00:00:00', 'code': 'CTEQ', 'description': 'Quayle action'}, {'recordDate': '1995-10-20 00:00:00', 'code': 'FWDX', 'description': 'Date Forwarded to Examiner'}, {'recordDate': '1995-09-13 00:00:00', 'code': 'A...', 'description': 'Response after Non-Final Action'}, {'recordDate': '1995-09-13 00:00:00', 'code': 'XT/G', 'description': 'Request for Extension of Time - Granted'}, {'recordDate': '1995-04-13 00:00:00', 'code': 'MCTNF', 'description': 'Mail Non-Final Rejection'}, {'recordDate': '1995-04-12 00:00:00', 'code': 'CTNF', 'description': 'Non-Final Rejection'}, {'recordDate': '1994-03-18 00:00:00', 'code': 'RQPR', 'description': 'Request for Foreign Priority (Priority Papers May Be Included)'}, {'recordDate': '1994-03-18 00:00:00', 'code': 'M844', 'description': 'Information Disclosure Statement (IDS) Filed'}, {'recordDate': '1994-03-18 00:00:00', 'code': 'WIDS', 'description': 'Information Disclosure Statement (IDS) Filed'}, {'recordDate': '1995-02-10 00:00:00', 'code': 'DOCK', 'description': 'Case Docketed to Examiner in GAU'}, {'recordDate': '1994-09-22 00:00:00', 'code': 'TR.Q', 'description': 'Transfer Inquiry'}, {'recordDate': '1994-09-07 00:00:00', 'code': 'FILM', 'description': 'Application Captured on Microfilm'}, {'recordDate': '1994-08-18 00:00:00', 'code': 'COMP', 'description': 'Application Is Now Complete'}, {'recordDate': '1994-06-08 00:00:00', 'code': 'MPTGR', 'description': 'Mail-Petition Decision - Granted'}, {'recordDate': '1994-03-18 00:00:00', 'code': 'PET.', 'description': 'Petition Entered'}, {'recordDate': '1994-02-18 00:00:00', 'code': 'INC/', 'description': 'Notice of Incomplete Application - Filing Date Not Assigned'}], 'LAST_INSERT_TIME': '2020-05-14T13:52:27Z', 'appCls': '382', 'appStatus': 'Patented Case', 'appStatusFacet': 'Patented Case', 'appStatus_txt': 'Patented Case', 'foreignPriority': [{'applicationNumberText': '08183369', 'priorityClaim': '5-7017/1993', 'countryName': 'JAPAN', 'filingDate': '01-19-1993'}], 'patentTitle': 'APPARATUS WHICH DETECTS LINES APPROXIMATING AN IMAGE BY REPEATEDLY NARROWING AN AREA OF THE IMAGE TO BE ANALYZED AND INCREASING THE RESOLUTION IN THE ANALYZED AREA ', 'appStatusDate': '1996-08-30T00:00:000Z', 'appAttrDockNumber': 'Q34261', 'inventors': [{'nameLineOne': 'SATO', 'nameLineTwo': 'JUN ', 'suffix': '', 'streetOne': '', 'streetTwo': '', 'city': 'CAMBRIDGE, ', 'geoCode': 'EN', 'country': '(GB)', 'rankNo': '1'}, {'nameLineOne': 'SAIKI', 'nameLineTwo': 'MITSUYOSHI ', 'suffix': '', 'streetOne': '', 'streetTwo': '', 'city': 'TSUKUBA CITY, ', 'geoCode': '', 'country': '(JP)', 'rankNo': '2'}], 'inventorsFacet': '{JUN||SATO||||CAMBRIDGE|EN|GB|IND|1},{MITSUYOSHI||SAIKI||||TSUKUBA CITY||JP|IND|2}', 'firstInventorFile': 'No', 'appType': 'Utility', 'appTypeFacet': 'Utility', 'corrAddrPostalCode': '20037', 'appClsSubCls': '382/104000', 'appClsSubClsFacet': '382/104000', 'patentIssueDate': '1996-09-10T00:00:00Z', 'corrAddrNameLineOne': 'SUGHRUE MION ZINN MACPEAK AND SEAS', 'attrnyAddr': [{'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '18879', 'fullName': 'Mion, John  ', 'phoneNum': '202-293-7060', 'regStatus': 'ACTIVE'}, {'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '19046', 'fullName': 'Zinn, Donald  Sr', 'phoneNum': '202-293-7060', 'regStatus': 'DELETED'}, {'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '19093', 'fullName': 'McMorrow, Robert  ', 'phoneNum': '202-663-7920', 'regStatus': 'ADMIN SUSPENDED'}, {'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '19292', 'fullName': 'MacPeak, Thomas  ', 'phoneNum': '202-293-7060', 'regStatus': 'DELETED'}, {'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '21092', 'fullName': 'Seas, Robert  Jr', 'phoneNum': '202-293-7060', 'regStatus': 'ADMIN SUSPENDED'}, {'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '22775', 'fullName': 'Sloan, Robert  ', 'phoneNum': '202-293-7060', 'regStatus': 'DELETED'}, {'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '23063', 'fullName': 'Mexic, Darryl  ', 'phoneNum': '202-663-7909', 'regStatus': 'ADMIN SUSPENDED'}, {'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '24513', 'fullName': 'Olexy, Peter  ', 'phoneNum': '202-293-7060', 'regStatus': 'ADMIN SUSPENDED'}, {'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '24625', 'fullName': 'OSHA, J  ', 'phoneNum': '202-293-7060', 'regStatus': 'DELETED'}, {'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '24835', 'fullName': 'Gubinsky, Louis  ', 'phoneNum': '202-467-8812', 'regStatus': 'ACTIVE'}, {'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '24861', 'fullName': 'Biggart, Waddell  II', 'phoneNum': '202-293-7060', 'regStatus': 'DELETED'}, {'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '25430', 'fullName': 'Landsman, Sheldon  ', 'phoneNum': '202-663-7933', 'regStatus': 'ACTIVE'}, {'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '25665', 'fullName': 'Bernstein, Howard  ', 'phoneNum': '703-623-5811', 'regStatus': 'ACTIVE'}, {'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '25200', 'fullName': 'Siegel, Neil  ', 'phoneNum': '202-293-7060', 'regStatus': 'ACTIVE'}, {'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '25426', 'fullName': 'Kasper, Alan  ', 'phoneNum': '202-293-7060', 'regStatus': 'ACTIVE'}, {'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '26577', 'fullName': 'Ruch, Joseph  Jr', 'phoneNum': '202-663-7931', 'regStatus': 'ACTIVE'}, {'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '26916', 'fullName': 'Inge, John  ', 'phoneNum': '202-339-8445', 'regStatus': 'ACTIVE'}, {'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '28703', 'fullName': 'Cushing, David  ', 'phoneNum': '202-663-7925', 'regStatus': 'ACTIVE'}, {'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '29710', 'fullName': 'Turner, Richard  ', 'phoneNum': '202-293-7060', 'regStatus': 'ACTIVE'}, {'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '30951', 'fullName': 'Mack, Susan  ', 'phoneNum': '202-293-7060', 'regStatus': 'ACTIVE'}, {'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '31484', 'fullName': 'Bernstein, Frank  ', 'phoneNum': '650-865-6500', 'regStatus': 'ACTIVE'}, {'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '30764', 'fullName': 'Kit, Gordon  ', 'phoneNum': '202-362-9470', 'regStatus': 'ACTIVE'}, {'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '32197', 'fullName': 'Boland, Mark  ', 'phoneNum': '202-293-7060', 'regStatus': 'ACTIVE'}, {'applicationId': None, 'registrationNo': '31333', 'fullName': 'Burchfiel, Kenneth  ', 'phoneNum': '202-293-7060', 'regStatus': 'ACTIVE'}], 'corrAddrCountryCd': 'US', 'corrAddrCity': 'WASHINGTON', 'appEntityStatus': 'UNDISCOUNTED', 'appConfrNumber': '9710', 'lastUpdatedTimestamp': '2020-05-16T14:51:30.854Z', 'appAttrDockNumberFacet': 'Q34261', 'appEntityStatusFacet': 'UNDISCOUNTED', '_version_': 1666859238011437056, 'firstInventorFileFacet': 'No', 'appLocationFacet': 'FILE REPOSITORY (FRANCONIA)', 'patentNumberFacet': '5555555'}], 'metadata': {'indexLastUpdatedDate': 'Mon Aug 24 19:15:48 EDT 2020', 'queryId': '09519f26-5026-4bf6-8762-97a82e1fa36b', 'responseHeader': {'zkConnected': True, 'status': 0, 'QTime': 107}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative solution that works:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

r = requests.get("https://developer.uspto.gov/ibd-api/v1/patent/application?patentNumber=9876543&start=0&rows=100")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")
text = soup.get_text()

r_dict = json.loads(str(text))
print(r_dict['response']['docs'][0]['inventor'][0])
```

The result now is just the inventor name.  For example, for the patent 9876543 the inventor results are:

Alexander, Thomas

Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there! Just dig a little deeper since the data is buried in the value of the `'docs'` key. Using the same result object you defined, you can get the inventor name by calling:

```
result['docs'][0]['inventorName']
```

For patent number 5555555, that returns `'JUN  SATO'`.

By the way, I believe APIs are generally the preferred way to obtain information when possible in favor of web-scraping through requests/BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could look at `patent_client`! It's a python module that searches the live USPTO and EPO databases using a Django-style API, including the Patent Examination Data System. The results from any query can then be cast into pandas DataFrames or Series with a simple `.to_pandas()` call.

```py
from patent_client import USApplication

app = USApplication.objects.get(patent_number="9876543")
app.inventors
# Produces a list of inventor objects, which can also be
# cast to a pandas dataframe with app.inventors.to_pandas()
```

A great place to start is the [User Guide Introduction](https://pypi.org/project/patent-client/)

[image: Patent Client Logo]

[PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/patent-client/) | [GitHub](https://github.com/parkerhancock/patent_client) | [Docs](https://patent-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

(Full disclosure - I'm the author and maintainer of patent_client)

Comment: do you know if there is a search limit of patents?